# PHP - How to turn a single array to multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I have a single array like:

```
array (
    '0' => 1,
    '1' => 3,
    '2' => 4
)
```

and I want to turn it to a multi-dimensional array like:

```
array (
    '1' =>
        array (
            '3' => '4'
        ),
)
```

Another single array :

```
array (
    '0' => 'a',
    '1' => 'b',
    '2' => 'c',
    '3' => 'd'
)
```

to :

```
array (
    'a' =>
        array (
            'b' =>
                array (
                    'c' => 'd'
                ),
        ),
),
```

How can I achieve this?

**Note**:
The array is dynamic, not always containing 3 or 4 elements.

Comment: the last one must be the real value, and everything before it become an index. sorry for my bad english, I updated my question.

Comment: your example have no logic

Comment: This sounds like a programming challenge - might be appropriate on codegolf or codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Wordica It does. But it takes some time to understand. He wants each value to become a new key with an array as value nested inside the previous array and have the last value set as value of the last nested array. It's quite hard to understand, but there is a logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

#### Simple *for* loop

First, use [array_pop()](http://php.net/array_pop) to *pop* (i.e. store and remove) the last value from the array. Then iterate from the end of the array, successively creating an array with the values (via [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values)):

```
function transformArray($input) {
    $accumulator = array_pop($input);
    $values = array_values($input);
    for($i = count($input)-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $accumulator = array($values[$i] => $accumulator);    
    }
    return $accumulator;
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/bq4MybHU6tKSruXt)

#### foreach loop

Using the code from the previous example, the [*for*](http://php.net/for) loop can be replaced with a [*foreach*](http://php.net/foreach) loop by utilizing [array_reverse()](http://php.net/array_reverse). That way we don't have to worry about when to start and stop the index values, index in to the array, etc.

```
function transformArray($input) {
    $accumulator = array_pop($input);
    $values = array_reverse(array_values($input));
    foreach($values as $value) {
        $accumulator = array($value => $accumulator);    
    }
    return $accumulator;
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/QXRSxmE02M3Dty82).

#### Functional approach: array_reduce()

[Array_reduce()](http://php.net/array_reduce) can be used to simplify the iteration. The first argument of array_reduce() is the input array, the second is a callback function and the third is the initial value. The parameters for the callback function are the *accumulator* value (from previous iterations) and the array element at the current array index). The initial value is used as the accumulator value for the first iteration, so we can pass the value that was popped from the end of the array.

```
function transformArray($input) {
    $accumulator = array_pop($input);
    $values = array_reverse(array_values($input));
    return array_reduce($values, function($accumulator, $element) {
        return array($element => $accumulator);
    }, $accumulator);
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/jemrkJqRrFBb5kzF).

#### Recursive Approach

Perhaps the simplest technique is to use a recursive function by employing [array_shift()](http://php.net/array_shift) to take the first element off the array and return an array with that element as the key and the value is the return value of calling the same function, unless there is only one item, in which case that one item is returned.

```
function transformArray($input) {
    if (count($input) == 1) {
        return $input[0];
    }
    return array(array_shift($input) => transformArray($input));
}
```

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/drTyxLn5jLt0P08B).

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is what I need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If it has always 3 elements:

```
  $temp = array (
            '0' => 1,
            '1' => 3,
            '2' => 4
        ); 

  $result = array();

  $result[$temp['0']] = array($temp['1'] => $temp['2']);
```

Comment: sorry, i've edited my question, the element is dynamic

Comment: So you want to keep pushing elements in new array ?

Can u give more examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I think there are better strategies, it's possible to use [eval()](http://php.net/eval) for this purpose:

```
<?php

/* Example array */
$arr1 = array(
    '0' => 'a',
    '1' => 'b',
    '2' => 'c',
    '3' => 'd'
);

$array_string = '';

/* Build array string */
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
    if($i < (count($arr1) - 1)){
        $array_string .= 'array ( \''. $arr1[$i] .'\' => ';
    } else {
        $array_string .= ' \''. $arr1[$i] .'\'';
    }
}

/* Close array string */
for($y = 0; $y < count($arr1); $y++){
    if($y < (count($arr1) - 2)){
        $array_string .= ' ), ';
    } else {
        $array_string .= ' )';
        break;
    }
}

/* Evaluate array string as PHP code and put it in $result */
$result = eval("return $array_string;");

/* Print the result */
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => d
                )

        )

)
```

But as I said, keep this quote in mind:

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Ask yourself why you need this. Is there another strategy available for what you want?